# Goldengate - op_ts is not detailed enough

Tags: oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, oracle-golden-gate

We have configured goldengate to generate avro files every 10 minutes, a single record with an X primary key can be inserted/updated within the same 10 minutes.

We've been receiving something like this (loading the data in snowflake into a timestamp_ntz column with length of 3 in miliseconds option):

```
optype      op_ts                         columnA
I           2023-07-31 16:15:59.015       "Hello"
U           2023-07-31 16:15:59.015       "Bye"
```

The update comes after the insert in the oracle database, when i make a select in snowflake with a rownumber ordering the op_ts in a descending order is returning the insert row and not the update,

You guys know any workaround? Maybe increasing the 3 miliseconds option in snowflake to 9 hoping to have a difference? Adding another parameter in the avro file of goldengate?

Thanks

Comment: if the operation time is caused by w trigger, there might be not solution to "getting finer resolution" if in effect they "happen at the same moment" from DB perspective.

Comment: That said, you could if you knew insert/update/delete's use these operations as a second order rank for things at the same timestamp (to the millisecond), because updates have to happen after inserts (or the insert would not happen, and updated cannot happen after the row is deleted)

Comment: thus weaving a decode('I',1, 'D', 3, 'U',2) could be used to break ties, if the data does not have multiple I/D cycles in the same millisecond.